# Display mysql table data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
INSERT INTO `stock` (`stock_id`, `product_attributes`, `product_id`, `qty`) VALUES
(43, '9,11', 2, 0),
(43, '9,12', 2, 10),
(44, '9,13', 2, 20),
(45, '10,11', 2, 0),
(46, '10,12', 2, 30),
(47, '10,13', 2, 50),
(48, '14,11', 2, 0),
(49, '14,12', 2, 0),
(50, '14,13', 2, 0);
```

I have a data table like this and a product column data is in substring format i.e. (9,11)

I have to list the products which have quantity zero on all occurrences.

```
SELECT 
    product_attributes,
    substring_index(product_attributes,',',-1) as one,
    substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)as two
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM stock 
     ORDER BY substring_index(product_attributes,',',1) ASC,
              substring_index(product_attributes,',',-1) ASC) AS ordered
WHERE 
    substring_index(product_attributes,',',1) NOT IN (
    SELECT substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)as one FROM stock WHERE qty!='0')
GROUP BY one'
```

I ran this query in database and got the correct output!

[image]

Now I want to display the column one, (comma) column two ... i.e. (14,11)

```
mysql_select_db('fly_stock');

// run query
$q = mysql_query('select product_attributes, substring_index(product_attributes,',',-1)as one,substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)as two from(SELECT * FROM stock order by substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)ASC, substring_index(product_attributes,',',-1)asc)as ordered where substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)not in (select substring_index(product_attributes,',',1)as one from stock where qty!='0')group by one');

//print the items   
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
  echo $row['one'] . " " . $row['two'];
  echo "<br>";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Help me to edit the php code so that 14,11 is displayed in PHP page.

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: i used single quotes thats the problem!
thanks @jage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) when you want [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
//print the items   
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
  echo $row['one'] . " " . $row['two'];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

On a side note, based on your php, your mysql_query() function is also likely producing an error since your query is in a string with single quotes and you have single quotes in your SQL that you're not escaping.

Comment: Default of mysql_fetch_array is providing associative array and numeric array. So that's not the problem. But you mentioned the quotes already ...

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here or do you really just want `one,two` output to PHP?

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
  echo implode("," array($row['one'], $row['two']));
  echo "<br>";
}
```